# Dashes in words, keeping e-mail and wi-fi as single words in Lucene.Net's tokenizer

Tags: lucene.net

I'm using Lucene.Net to tokenize blog posts.

```
var db = new DataClassesDataContext();
var articles = (from article in db.Articles
                select article).ToList();
var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30);
using (var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED))
{
    foreach (var article in articles)
    {
        var luceneDocument = new Document();
        luceneDocument.Add(new Field("ArticleID", article.articleID.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
        luceneDocument.Add(new Field("Title", article.title, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.YES));
        writer.AddDocument(luceneDocument);
    }
    writer.Optimize();
}
```

The resulting term vectors contain unexpected word splits, for example the word "e-mails" has become the two words "e" and "mails" and "wi-fi" has become "wi" and "fi". Some answers (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13572562/575530) about Solr) suggests that I need to use the "`ClassicAnalyzer` rather than a `StandardAnalyzer`, as `StandardAnalyzer` now always treats hyphens as a delimiter", but I cannot see where the `ClassicAnalyzer` lives and [the documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_4_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/ClassicAnalyzer.html) suggests I'd need 3.1 (Lucene.Net goes up to 3.0 I think).

How do I avoid treating dashes in words as word boundaries?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'd suggest `KeywordAnalyzer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`WhitespaceAnalyzer`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/WhitespaceAnalyzer.html) which splits at whitespace only.